# learnpython.org modules exercise

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, python-import

## Hello community,

**[ Preamble ] :**
I come from a BASH scripting background *(still learning there as well)* and decided it might benefit my learning process by venturing into another language. The natural choice for me seemed to be Python. I began studying a bit and have been going through the exercises found on www.learnpython.org. Particularly, [Modules and Packages](http://www.learnpython.org/Modules%20and%20Packages).

**[ Problem ] :**

`Import` the module **re** and `print` out alphabetically **sorted**, all functions in the module that contain the word `find`.

**[ Tried ] :**

```
# import the module.
import re

# store output of dir(re) in reLST as string list.
''' I believe that's what happens, correct? '''
reLST = dir(re)

# iterate over reLST and assign m strings matching word containing find.
for element in reLST:
    m = re.match("(find\w+)", element)

# Here it prints out the matches, but only using the function .groups()
''' Won't work using print sorted(m)  ---why? '''
# Found tutorial online, but no real understanding of .groups() function use.     
    if m:
        print sorted(m.groups())
```

**[ Expected Output ] :**
['findall', 'finditer']

**[ My Output ] :**
['findall']
['finditer']

**[ Question ] :**
Technically, the code works and does output all *strings* grabbed from `dir(re)`, but on a new line. I'm guessing this is done as part of the `.groups()` function? What would be a good way of getting the desired output in the correct format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should collect the results in a list, and then sort them:

```
import re


results = []
for element in dir(re):
    m = re.match("(find\w+)", element)
    if m:
        results.append(m.group(1))

print sorted(results)
```

Also, instead of `re`, you can use `startswith()`:

```
import re


results = []
for element in dir(re):
    if element.startswith('find'):
        results.append(element)

print sorted(results)
```

or, the same thing in one line using `list comprehension`:

```
import re

print sorted([element for element in dir(re) if element.startswith('find')])
```

If the word `find` can be anywhere in the string, you should use `in` instead of `startswith()`:

```
import re

print sorted([element for element in dir(re) if 'find' in element])
```

Comment: Excellent solutions. The first one was not accepted as the correct format for the problem but the others worked just fine. Thank you for the assistance in that area. I could still use some feedback in regards to the comment sections, but other than that, fantastic!